# How can I checkout github project on xCode 5 correctly?

Tags: xcode, git, github

How can I checkout github project on xCode 5 correctly?

I have done checkout from xCode (Source Control - Check Out...). But now I can't commit any changes to the repository (Source Control - Commit...). All "Source Control" commands are disabled on the xCode except "Check Out...". But ".git" folder presents on the project's folder. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/git-source-control-in-xcode/), which describes your case after having created locally a git repo and done some commits:

> The git repository is ready, but if you go back to Xcode and open the Source Control menu, you’ll find out that everything is still disabled.

[image: http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/t10_7_disabled_source_control.jpg]

> That’s because Xcode doesn’t get notified automatically about our manual git repository addition.
>
> So, close Xcode using the menu **`Xcode > Quit Xcode`** and re-open it.
>
> Now, in the NoGitExample project if you open the Source Control menu once again, you’ll see that all options have been enabled, just like if we would have added the git repository along with the project creation.

[image: http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/t10_8_enabled_source_control.jpg]

Comment: xCode authors are bad people!